# Удаление части столбца

Tags: sql-server

Имеется примерно вот такой запрос:

```
select client_id , number 
from abc
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, каким образом я могу удалть процент данных, из столбца number? Или же заменить на null.
Пробывал через delete, но таким образом удалялось вместе с id. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: что значит процент даннных? заменить на null это update

Comment: Мне нужно удалить 40% значений number. Желательно рандомно. Что бы по итогу остались все id , а в number остались к примеру 123 или 345 или 235.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в SQL удаление применяется к строкам. Вам нужно обновление строки и установка значения NULL. Задача посути разбивается на следующие шаги

- отсортировать данные в случайном порядке
- выбрать 40% данных
- обновить их, указав значение `NULL`

для сортировки можно использовать `ORDER BY newid()`. Для выборки 40% использовать TOP 40 PERCENT. Для обновления хорошо подойдет CTE.

Итого имеем:

Входные данные

```
declare @abc table (client_id int, v int);
insert into @abc values 
(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5);

select * from @abc;
```

Обновление

```
with data AS (
   SELECT TOP 40 PERCENT client_id, v 
   FROM @abc
   ORDER BY newid()
)
UPDATE data set v = null;

select * from @abc;
```